# bootstrap v3.3.2 - col-xs-* not displaying on small screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

With this code when the width of the container is less than 792px the content of the div with the class 'col-xs-6' disappear.

```
<div class="cont">
    <div class="top">
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center col-xs-6">
            <small>id:</small>
            0001
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center col-xs-6">
            <small>reference:</small>
            PRJ1
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
            <small>name:</small>
            Project 1
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

how can I display it?

Comment: Since 'col-xs' triggers when the screen is lower then 768px, did you resize your screen far enough down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add class name row to top class

```
<div class="cont">
<div class="top row">
<div class="col-md-3 text-center col-xs-6">
<small>id:</small>
0001
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 text-center col-xs-6">
<small>reference:</small>
PRJ1
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 text-center">
<small>name:</small>
Project 1
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted